# document.implementation.createHTMLDocument browser support?

Tags: javascript, dom, cross-browser, browser-support

I would like to use it but don't know which browsers support it.

I have tried searching it on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMImplementation.createHTMLDocument) but there's no *Browser compatibility* section

Comment: Maybe test the browsers you're concerned about, then update that MDN page with what you found.

Comment: @CrazyTrain But I don't have all versions of all browsers installed on my PC, because I have windows, so if I install lots of programs the registry becomes a messy and PC slows down. And I have XP, so I can't install a newer IE than IE8, which doesn't support it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On August 15, the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMImplementation.createHTMLDocument) article was updated with a *Browser compatibility* section:

```
Feature       | Chrome | Firefox (Gecko) | Internet Explorer  | Opera | Safari
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Basic support | (Yes)  | 4.0 (2.0) [1]   | 9.0                | (Yes) | (Yes)

[1] The title parameter has only been made option in Firefox 23.
```